# How to make currently viewed list heading bold

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a sidebar on a Wordpress page. This sidebar contains a side map, which is a overview of the page.

If I click on "Impressum" or any item that is a sub-list-item of "Impressum" I want "Impressum" to be **bold**. How is that possible?

The same behavior should occur for every "header-item-element". See the image below for better explanation.

The css I have for the widged / sidebar / list is:

```
.widget ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display: block;
}
.widget li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 3%;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.widget li:before{
    content: '';
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 11px;
    left: 0;
}
.widget li a {
    color:#272727;
}
.widget li a:hover {
    color:#E96656
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make an item bold look at the HTML code of the sidebar. Usually sidebars add an extra class to the item that is selected. Then you can reference that item in the CSS.

For example, if the added class by the sidebar is called "active", your code can be something like:

```
 li.active{
 font-weight: bold;}
```